# Generar un PDF en Flutter

Tags: mysql, sql, pdf, flutter

Estoy desarrollando una app en Flutter y me gustaría generar un pdf al darle a un botón. El pdf quiero que contenga los datos sacados de una sentencia sql, los datos los tengo almacenados en MySql, y los muestro por pantalla al usuario, pero también quiero darle la opción al usuario de sacarlos en un pdf por si quiere revisar los datos sin conexión, el problema es que no encuentro ninguna forma de hacerlo que funcione, he probado ya con los plugins de aqui https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=pdf pero nada.

Comment: ¿Y cuál ha sido el problema con los plugins? Deberías dar detalles concretos para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Básicamente el problema es que no me hacen nada, no me generan ningún pdf, o me dicen que el archivo de pdf es inaccesible (cosa que no entiendo por que se supone que lo estoy creando) @AntonioVenerosoContreras

Comment: Saludos te sugiero agregar tu codigo lo que has intentado asi de esta manera entender mejor tu problema y dar con una posible respuesta.!!